# Constant Speed of Geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

Let *V* be the set of smooth functions $ f : [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R $ such that $ \int_0^1 f(t) dt = k $. If $ F : V \rightarrow \Bbb R $ is given by $ F(f) = \int_0^1 f(t)^2 dt $, then show that the only critical point of *F* is the constant function $ f(t) = k$. Deduce that geodesics have constant speed.

This looks like it should be pretty straight forward, but I can't manage it. I someone able to give me a (fairly sizeable!) hint, but not just a full solution. (If I still can't get it after a hint, then I may ask for a full solution!)

(I can show that $ f(t) = k $ is *a* critical point, but not that it is the *only* critical point.)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set this up as a constrained optimization problem with Lagrange multipliers:

$$\mathcal{L}(f,\lambda) = \int_0^1 (f(t))^2\ dt + \lambda\bigg( \int_0^1 f(t)\ dt - k\bigg).$$

Now if you take a compactly supported perturbation $\epsilon\phi$ and differentiate at $\epsilon = 0$, a critical point must satisfy

$$0 = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon = 0} \mathcal{L}(f+\epsilon\phi,\lambda) = \cdots$$

What Euler-Lagrange equation must $f(t)$ satisfy?

To finish the problem, since you know $\int_0^1f(t)\ dt = k$, what can you conclude about $f$?

Comment: Thanks for your response. By $$0 = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon = 0} \mathcal{L}(f+\epsilon\phi,\lambda) = \cdots$$
do you mean
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {{(\mathcal{L}(f+\epsilon\phi,\lambda) - \mathcal{L}(f,\lambda)})/\epsilon } = 0 ?$$

Comment: Let $ G = f(t)^2 $

$G$ must then satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$ { \partial G \over \partial f }  = {d \over dt}({\partial G \over \partial f'}),$$
but $${\partial G \over \partial f'} = 0,$$
so we have the so-called "first integral"
$$ { \partial G \over \partial f } = 0 \Rightarrow G(t,f,f') = h(t,f').$$
But we have $ G = f(t)^2 $ also. Therefore $G$ is constant. The condition $\int_0^1 f(t) dt = k$ then guarantees $f(t) = k$.

Comment: Is this correct logic? :)

Comment: @SmileySam Yes, in my response, that is how the derivative should be interpreted. $\mathcal{L}(f+\epsilon\phi,\lambda)$ is a real-valued function on the line.

Comment: But is my argument sound, or does it need more?
Thanks :)

Comment: @SmileySam It looks good -- I'm sorry I couldn't verify it immediately.

Comment: Thank you. :) And no problem. (: